# How to navigate stack frames in Emacs debugger?

Tags: debugging, debug

I'm trying to debug the infamous `Unrecognized entry in undo list undo-tree-canary`, and after having Emacs debugger triggered on error, I want to move back and forth between stack frames and to examine state of variables. Sort of what `frame 3` command in `gdb` would do.

Unfortunately I haven't found this question asked before, and searching through Emacs documentation haven't been fruitful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply move point in the `*Backtrace*` buffer to the corresponding line of the frame you're interested in.

> examine state of variables

Then press `v` (`debugger-toggle-locals`) to show local variables in the frame, or `e` (`debugger-eval-expression`) to evaluate an expression in the frame's context.  Note that you won't have access to lexical variables when the function is byte compiled.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. For example, the trace shows values of arguments that `primitive-undo` was called with, in particular "list" arg is set to "(undo-tree-canary)" text. But when I move point in \*Backtrace\* buffer over this line and evaluate `list` expecting to see its value, I get "void variable list". Same happens if I additionally press enter over the function, thus getting redirected to the source. The source of `simple.el` isn't byte-compiled for me.

Comment: I just figured I should use `e` to inspect variables in \*Backtrace\* buffer *(I've used `M-:` instead)*. Still, for every possible stack frame, when I evaluate with `e` the argument that the function in frame was called with, I get "void variable", even though I can see value of the argument inside the backtrace.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Are you stopping in `primitive-undo` using `debug-on-entry`? I noticed it seems to mess up the frames so the debugger gets a bit confused.

Comment: I use `toggle-debug-on-error`, can it have a similar problem? Btw, thanks for the hint about `v`, when I press it over `primitive-undo`, I get only 2 local variables, and none of them are arguments of the function, [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/f6t6K6d.png). I guess this is a bug in Emacs itself, right?

Comment: @Hi-Angel, hmm sort of works for me, I'm seeing the arguments to the function, but I can only evaluate them in the frame below that, [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/oWYeRRq.png)

Comment: @Hi-Angel "The source of simple.el isn't byte-compiled for me" - to be clear, you have to also load `simple.el`; by default you have `simple.elc` loaded which is byte compiled.

Comment: Oh, so you was right all that time, about the file being byte-compiled! I was sure this is not the case, because I have `ido-mode` enabled, and when I do `C-x C-f` it seems the ido-mode just skips all files with `.elc` extensions, as if they weren't there. I.e. I was confused into thinking that none of files there has their `.elc` counterpart. Using `(load "simple.el")` made it work.

Comment: Thanks @npostavs - the debugger-toggle-locals is an eye-opener. Also works on let bindings etc...